# Hyperparameters tunning for Lstm (python)

Tags: python, lstm, hyperparameters

Is there any Library for hyperparameter turning in Lstm except keras because I need to use metaheuristic algorithm particularly swarm algorithms

I am working on Google colab.

I searched a bit and found pygad  but there is no example about how to coding long short term memory in pygad

and I couldn't find any example how to coding parameter tunning with metaheuristic on Lstm without being Library

Actually I want to I hyperparameter tunning on long short-term memory with meta heuristic algorithm based swarm

Comment: This site specifically disallows questions that are "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more". So, maybe you could read the [tour] and [ask] pages, and the [help] topics, and the [mre] page, and see if there's a way you could rewrite this that fits this site's guidelines. You have no code at all and this is a high level question. Maybe you could get the help you need at one of these ML-focused StackExchange sites, but keep in mind they all have their own guidelines, too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254090/858527